# How to fix positioning? Looks "corrcet" on a laptop and "wrong" on the other?

Tags: html, positioning

So here is my "code"

```html
<p style="left: 40px; top: 1125px; width: 30px; position: absolute;" <a href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/26TID9N98ORTA" target=_blank"><img src="http://www.reneedunaway.com/images/icon_amazon.gif" </a></p>
```

Its positioned where I wanted to be on my 17" ASUS G74 but on my 17" ASUS K70IO is positioned like 100px lower.
Been looking for an answer since yesterday but no luck :/
Can someone help me please? :) 
Thanx in advance.

Comment: Maybe, *pixel density* ? In any case, don't expect something amazing with `top: 1125px` !

Comment: @Stuffix  yeah but I have not Idea what am I doing ( never worked with HTML before or anything, I'm just a graphic designer ) but now I'm trying to do a layout for a page  ( similar to the layouts which we were using on Hi5 in the good old days ) I just want it to look on other browsers/devices as I see it on my main.

Comment: I see. And if you're using `pt` or `em`, does it still the same ? (And maybe .. InVision will be your final solution, aha ! http://www.invisionapp.com/)

Comment: @Stuffix With em is the same, I will try pt right now

Comment: @Stuffix nope, didn't work

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this. Set a higher level wrapper div to position:relative and height of 100% and then set the other `<div>` to position:absolute but position based on the bottom instead of the top.  This way it doesn't matter how tall the screen is it will always position to the bottom of it.  This could cause other issues but not given any other html to look at this is what I have for now.

```
<div style="height:100%; position:relative; border:1px solid red">
<div style="position:absolute; bottom:0px; left:40px"><p style="" <a   href="http://www.amazon.com/gp/registry/wishlist/26TID9N98ORTA" target=_blank"><img src="http://www.reneedunaway.com/images/icon_amazon.gif" </a></p></div>
```